# Why does this SQL query not work?

Tags: php, mysql

I have been bugging by head over this, but couldn't get this to work. What's wrong with this?

```
        $query="Select studentid,firstname,lastname,pts from students where collegeid=4";
        $result=mysql_query($query);
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $pts=$row['pts'];
        $name=$row['firstname']." ".$row['lastname'];
        $rank=  mysql_num_rows(queryMysql("Select distinct pts from students where pts>=$pts"));
        echo<<<_END
        <a href="student_profile.php?studentid=$row[studentid]" style="text-decoration: none;">
        <div class="apps_each your_rank">
            <span style="margin-right:5px;">$rank</span>
        <div class="dp_small_c"><img class="dp_small" src="upload/$row[studentid].jpg"/></div>
        <span class="apps_names">$name</span>
            <div style="float:right">
        <img src='pts.png' /><span>$row[pts]</span>
        <img src='level.png' /><span>Level 1</span>
        </div>
        </div>
        </a>
```

_END;

The error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1.

Surprisingly, below one(removing the WHERE clause) works. Why?

```
$row=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("Select studentid,pts,firstname,lastname from students"));
```

Table structure:

Everything's fine with table and its columns, because this query works everywhere else, only not here!

Comment: Is that a direct copy / paste from your non-working code? Also, MySQL extension bad (deprecated); PDO / MySQLi good

Comment: yes that's a copy paste from my code. I have been trying to learn PDO lately.

Comment: Wait, that code wouldn't produce that error. You'd need `mysql_error` for that. Please add the *real* code to your question

Comment: Then you should take the opportunity to try it with PDO, that should be quick and might solve your problem at the same time ;)

Comment: try to seperate mysql_fetch_array and mysql_query in different rows in your code. It could be that the input for mysql_fetch_array is wrong because the query returns no rows.

Comment: @Phil : yes exactly. I removed every occurence of `mysql_error` in the page, still it throws an error! What's wrong??

Comment: What happens when you put this ... WHERE collegeid='4'" ??

Comment: If you try the code I gave as an answer, does it print errors and if so what?

Comment: @eyetea : is it supposed to throw out an error if the query returns no rows? I don't think that's true. Plus, I tried seperating them already - no luck.

Comment: @DanyP yeah, I am too scared to try the PDO for now. Let me get to that when I learn it. Could you please help me with the deprecated "mysql_*" functions for now?

Comment: @StBlade - tried, no luck. Moreover, numbers don't need quotes.

Comment: @kamal0808 have you had a chance to try my suggestion (answer below)?

Comment: I found the problem, please see the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `$query` in the question returns an empty row, then the variable beneath it remained unassigned - i.e., `$pts` and `$name` have no entities.

However, the query below them uses the variable `$pts`, which presumably has to store some value - which, when not, throws the above posted MYSQL error. The use of function queryMysql() for this query further clears the issue, as it was defined as below:

```
function queryMysql($query)
{
    $result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    return $result;
}
```

Hence, the MySql error.

Answer (score 0):

You mentionned in the comments that you wanted to use PDO. Here's what you can try:

```
$username = "enterUsername";
$password = "enterPass";
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDatabase', $username, $password);

$query = $conn->prepare("Select studentid,pts,firstname,lastname from students where collegeid=:id");

$query->execute(array(
    ':id' => 4
));

// get errors if there are
$errors = $query->errorInfo();
echo "<pre>";
print_r($errors);
echo "</pre>";

$results = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // can also be fetchAll if you have more than 1 row.


// to test and check results
echo "<pre>";
print_r($results);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use this library for all MySQL querying - http://www.meekro.com.

Your select query becomes like this:

```
// Load Library
require 'meekrodb.2.2.class.php';

// Setup DB Connection
DB::$user       = 'my_database_user';
DB::$password   = 'my_database_password';
DB::$dbName     = 'my_database_name';
DB::$host       = '123.111.10.23';

// Where clause
$collegeid = 4;

// Exec Query
$row = DB::queryFirstRow("Select studentid,pts,firstname,lastname from students where collegeid = %d", $collegeid);
```

src: http://www.meekro.com/docs.php#anchor_queryfirstrow

Comment: It's a nice library, making things easier. Although I wonder if it guarantees the same security as PDO does.

Comment: It has a good track record in terms of SQL Injection protection as well as being better than pdo - have a read http://www.meekro.com/pdo.php

Comment: of course the SQL Injection prevention only works, if you use the library properly, i.e. use parameterised query (like in my example) (i.e. %s is replaced with string, %d is replaced with decimal/int etc... and the library takes care of escaping the parameters for your query) - more info here http://www.meekro.com/quickstart.php